# Do you know of any OWL 2 tools/libraries implemented in C#?

Tags: c#, rdf, semantic-web, owl

Do you know of any OWL 2 tools/libraries implemented in C#? There are some in Java, but am I to rewrite them to C# or invent my own ones If I prefer .Net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there aren't any that I know of.

I've been talking with the guys at Clark & Parsia about bringing Pellet support to my [dotNetRDF](http://www.dotnetrdf.org) library hopefully by year end but I assume you're talking about much fuller OWL 2 support e.g. a C# implementation of the OWLAPI which certainly won't be provided for my library anytime soon

Comment: Is this answer still actual? I would love to know more about it. Do you know about this API? Link: https://owlapinet.codeplex.com/

Comment: No probably never going to happen and no I don't know anything about that other API

Comment: OK, thank you. Than I will try the other API myself and provide a new answer if it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Rowlex](http://rowlex.nc3a.nato.int/). Here is a quote from the site:

> It allows programmers to create and browse RDF documents while keeping the focus on the  business objects. It abstracts away the level of RDF triples and elevates the level of the programming work to (OWL) classes and properties.

I have taken a look at their docs and the library looks good.

Answer (score 0):

As davidseth said, Rowlex is I think your only choice at the moment.